# linking on bootstrap dropdown not working

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, bootstrap-4, routes

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="bags" id="navbarDropdown3" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        More <i class="fas fa-angle-down ml-3"></i></a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown3">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

here is the code for dropdown

```
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: none;
}

.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown > .dropdown-toggle:active {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

this is the css for displaying dropdown on hover

clicking on the link doesnt navigate to the page...
i am using express as the backend n typing the link in the navbar works but not clicking the link..

i tried adding data-target but also doesnt seems to work..
i treid setting pointer-event to auto but tat also doesnt deems to work..

[image: image showing the link]

Comment: Did you check your console for errors?

Comment: its not giving any error.

Comment: i tried adding jus plain <a href ="bags">xyz</a> and tat seems to work...but its not working on dropdown.

Comment: looks like all your `href` are pointing to `#` as `href="#"` where it should be pointing your express routes.

Comment: href in list of dropdown are pointiing to # but the main dropdown href is point to bags..i tried adding href in sub-menu and its working but not on the dropdown text..

Comment: i tried adding `$('#scndbar > li > .dropdown-toggle').click(function () {
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
});` but tat also doesnt seems to work..

Comment: Have you included/referenced the core files properly?. The order should be `jquery` then `bootstrap`

Comment: yup tat is all fine..page can navigated from other `href` on page but its not being navigating by dropdown.

Comment: I have updated the working answer below. Please let me know if that doe the work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `data-hover="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"`

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown" style="cursor:pointer">
<a class="nav-link  dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown3" data-hover="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="services.html">SERVICES</a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown3">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: tat also doesnt seems to work but when i remove `dropdown-toggle` class from anchor tag and change `data-toggle` to `data-hover` it works.....is it ok to remove `dropdown-toggle` class from anchor????

Comment: Yes you can remove that.I didn't use  any `dropdown-toggle` in the solution. You can do that by `data-hover` as mentioned. Please accept and upvote my answer if you feel that as helpful. Happy coding

Comment: it was a a very silly mistake on my part...i set the pointer event to none and tat was causing the problem..after i removed the pointer event line in css and added dropdown-toggle class its working...and yes the keypoint was to change data-toggle to data-hover...

Answer (score 1):

This link might be a help.

[Bootstrap Dropdown Hover](https://kybarg.github.io/bootstrap-dropdown-hover/)

> Wrap the dropdown's trigger and the dropdown menu within `.dropdown` as it is important. Add `data-hover="dropdown"` to the main action button or link to activate hover event.

Keypoint is to add `data-hover="dropdown"`

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">
   Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#">One more dropdown</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#">One more dropdown</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          ...
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i am using bootstrap 4....rest everything is same but only way it worked for me is to remove dropdown-toggle class and replace data-toggle with data-hover....i was jus curious to know will removing dropdown-toggle class will cause any trouble in future..